# Jomsocial multi profile user approval notification

Tags: joomla

I am using jomsocial multi profile for user registration . Some profile needs administration approval to complete registration process .

But the problem is administrator is no getting any notification to approve new user registration .

How can I solve this problem?

I am using Joomla! 2.5.2 Stable and jomsocial 2.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed line 911  of /components/com_community/controllers/register.php

from

```
if( $type == 'registration_complete' && (C_JOOMLA_15 || (!$requireApproval && !C_JOOMLA_15)))
```

to

```
if( $type == 'registration_complete' && (C_JOOMLA_15 || ($requireApproval && !C_JOOMLA_15)))
```

and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the backend of Joomla as administrator then click on the menu.

Go to `Users > User Manager`, then click on the admin user that you wish to receive the notifications for, and set the "**Receive System emails**" to Yes. Here is a picture to help you http://screencast.com/t/p1LgQFVt

IF this helped you, please consider supporting the proposal for a Joomla StackOverflow by clicking follow here >>> http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers

Comment: I tried this before posting this question. Any other suggestion ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know then. Perhaps you could try upgrading to  Jomsocial 2.6. The changelog says that they've made a lot of changes with the notification system. Perhaps they've fixed the problem?

Comment: I changed 911 no line of /components/com_community/controllers/register.php from if( $type == 'registration_complete' && (C_JOOMLA_15 || (!$requireApproval && !C_JOOMLA_15)))  to if( $type == 'registration_complete' && (C_JOOMLA_15 || ($requireApproval && !C_JOOMLA_15))) and it is working now thanks

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it! Please write it as an answer for this question. Also thanks for supporting the Joomla StackOverflow :)